# I need help deleting all text/characters between certain characters on Notepad++

Tags: encryption, notepad++, code

Ok, so here is the text I've got:

`--[[lWjY]] --[[jAouQKe]]--[[SyXZxSmUQ]] --[[BC]]--[[jiynRfVxz]] --[[KhIysiNCC]]--[[ddmGYn]] --[[cYv]]--[[_y]] --[[q-tAXL]]--[[bNgAZ_aY]] --[[C]]--[[iY]] --[[LZIpK]]--[[v]] --[[qO]]TriggerServerEvent--[[DyBUmXd]] --[[kx]]=--[[zWJWj]] --[[HFaa]]function(b,--[[V]] --[[sLQzqLfQ]]...)`

It is encrypted. I'm wanting to remove the simple encryption. I could do it manually, but I thought to ask if anyone knows an easier way. here's what this same code should looks like:

`-- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- --TriggerServerEvent-- --=-- --function(b,-- --...)`

^^This is what I want it to look like, just anything between a: [[ ]] to be deleted, as well as the [[ ]] itself. Then manually I can just find an replace all the '-' and it should look like this:

`TriggerServerEventfunction(b,`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, once you know that in regex `?` means non-greedy
match, because otherwise Notepad++ will just gobble up all the text.

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for the Replace dialog and enter:

Find what : `\[\[.*?\]\]`
Replace with : empty (nothing)
Search mode : Regular expression

Click Replace All to execute.

The result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does the job in a single step:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `--\[\[.+?]] ?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
--          # 2 hyphens
\[\[        # 2 open square brackets, have to be escaped because they have special meaning in regex
.+?         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
]]          # 2 close square brackets
 ?          # optional white space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]